# Mongo db first groupby count not able to display

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
[
 { "$match": {  
     "created":{  
         "$gte": ISODate("2015-07-19T07:26:49.045Z")
     },
     "created":{  
         "$lte": ISODate("2015-07-20T07:37:56.045Z")
     }
 }},
 { "$group:{  
     "_id":{  
         "ln":"$l.ln",
         "cid":"$cid"
     },
     "appCount":{ "$sum": 1 }
 }},
 {  "$group": {  
     "_id": {  "ln":"$_id.ln" },
     "cusappCount": {  "$sum": 1 }
 }},
 {  "$sort":{ "_id.ln":1  } }
]
```

In above mongo db query I am not able to display the appcount in result.. I am able to display cusappCount.  Could anyone please help me on this

Comment: The above code is single query

Comment: You need to project the first count into the second group, but the two counts seem incompatible at glance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`$match`** is wrong to start with and does not do what you think. It is only selecting the "second" statement:

```js
"created":{  
    "$lte": ISODate("2015-07-20T07:37:56.045Z")
 }
```

So your selections are incorrect to start with.

That and other corrections below:

```js
[
    { "$match": {  
         "created": {  
             "$gte": ISODate("2015-07-19T07:26:49.045Z"),
             "$lte": ISODate("2015-07-20T07:37:56.045Z")
         }
     }},
     { "$group":{   
         "_id": {  
             "ln":"$l.ln",
             "cid":"$cid"
         },
         "appCount":{ "$sum": 1 }
     }},
     { "$group": {  
         "_id": "$_id.ln",
          "cusappCount": { "$sum": "$appCount" },
          "distinctCustCount": { "$sum": 1 }
     }},
     {  "$sort":{ "_id": 1  } }
]
```

Which seems to be what you are trying to do.

So your earier "count" is then passed to `$sum` when grouping at a "broader" level. The "second" count is just for the "distinct" items in the earlier key.

If you are trying to "retain" the values of "appCount", then the problem here is that your "grouping" is "taking away" the detail level that appears at. So for what it is woth, then this is where you use "arrays" in an output structure:

```js
[
    { "$match": {  
         "created": {  
             "$gte": ISODate("2015-07-19T07:26:49.045Z"),
             "$lte": ISODate("2015-07-20T07:37:56.045Z")
         }
     }},
     { "$group":{   
         "_id": {  
             "ln":"$l.ln",
             "cid":"$cid"
         },
         "appCount":{ "$sum": 1 }
     }},
     { "$group": {  
         "_id": "$_id.ln",
          "cusappCount": { "$sum": 1 },
          "custs": { "$push": {
              "cid": "$_id.cid", "appCount": "$appCount" 
          }}
     }},
     {  "$sort":{ "_id": 1  } }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Blakes Seven

Comment: My document structure

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55acf4819d735e293623c95b"),
    "l" : {
        "ln" : "Khammam",
        "lgps" : {
            "llon" : "17.2333738",
            "llat" : "17.2333738"
        },
        "lc" : "India",
        "lz" : "507001"
    },
 
    "cid" : "ABCD",
       "created" : ISODate("2015-07-20T13:15:45.198Z")
}

I need how many entries for a particular location and how many distinct cid entries for a location. Could you please help me on this

Comment: @user1920 It's considered bad SO etiquette so ask more questions in comments(or update original post with more questions).  Accept this as the answer and create a new question for your new issue.

Comment: @user1920 The first pipeline form ( since it was not completely clear what you were asking ) does exactly what you are asking for. So first you are counting on the "ln" "cid" combination at that level. When you `$sum` that total grouping by "ln" it becomes the "total for ln". Because "cid" was part of the grouping and now removed `{ "$sum": 1 }` "counts distinct cid"` from that grouping. You `$group` two times. That explains the answer given.